# Menu Dropdown is behind segment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

I've started using semantic UI, and I am struggle with an issue that doesn't seem to be a z-index issue.

For some reason the dropdown in the menu is always behind the segment. I worked around using:

```
.go-behind {
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

But the issue now is that I cannot click on links.

I've created a fiddle to explain this issue better:
https://jsfiddle.net/bruno911/L1mfrd4f/1/

Comment: It's little issues like these that lead me to believe that Semantic UI isn't ready for primetime. The author doesn't seem to care about these kinds of issues.

Comment: I've tried many frontends, and I believe Semantic ui is the best framework, if you read at the source code, it is the perfect code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS code to :

```
/*Override*/
.ui.menu {
    opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.go-behind {
        position: relative !important;
        //z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

*points to note*
1) Opacity creates a new stack-frame.
2) Never use *!important* in CSS, if some bug appears, it will be really very hard to debug.

Comment: Great spot! I needed to opacity 0.8, so I removed it and I add a background image with opacity 0.8. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue, and spent a heap of time trying to fiddle with the z-index, only to find this quick fix. Great!